# What's the best course of action for my Hogwarts question?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty, community-wiki

My question ("[What changes have been made to Hogwarts throughout the series?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129604/what-changes-have-been-made-to-hogwarts-throughout-the-series)) asks for some details from the movies about the changes in Hogwarts castle from film to film.

What's the best way to get a good answer for future visitors to the site?

1. Set some sort of **bounty** on the question?
2. Start a **CW answer** and hope users will add to it over time?
3. Some **other** idea?

I haven't had much luck with setting bounties in the past so I'm not very hopeful about idea #1 but I also think a CW would be kinda boring. Any thoughts? What's the best way to end up with a decent answer?

Comment: Lock DVK, Valorum, alexwlchan, and Slytherincess in a cell together and force them to cooperate to answer your question. (Note: said cell must have internet access.)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Alright DVK, Valorum, alexwlchan, and Slytherincess, consider yourselves locked in a room. If I hear any complaining, you all have to watch Twilight and Phantom Menace back to back. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that your question is very broad and not a little dull. It's not *unanswerable*, but doing so would require someone to put in an inordinate amount of effort for a question that is very poorly scoped.

I'm reasonably sure that any of the users [mentioned above](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9843/whats-the-best-course-of-action-for-my-hogwarts-question/9844#comment27801_9843) could answer it if they were minded to (as could you), so it's just a matter of motivating someone to do the leg-work that you seem unwilling to do yourself. That says "bounty" to me.

Comment: [New Hogwarts for DH](http://www.cosforums.com/archive/index.php/t-114483.html)

Comment: [Inconsistent Aspects of the Movies: Everything Changes When the Director Changes](http://www.cosforums.com/archive/index.php/t-114483.html)

Comment: I think it originally sounded like I was asking for loads of details, so I've edited my question. I hope that clarifies things. Loads and loads of more detailed questions get asked and answered on this site all the time so I don't know why mine would be too much or anything. hmm.

Comment: @RedCaio Looks like you got what you were looking for :-)